# Typescript extend module (augmentation)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

i want to extend a installed module (Mongoose) with my own class and function.
I wrote the function and class and they work fine.

Now i wanted to add them to the `mongoose` module.
So what i have now is this file:
**mongoInstance.ts**

```
import * as mg from 'mongoose'

class _Schema extends mg.Schema {
    constructor(definition?: mg.SchemaDefinition, options?: mg.SchemaOptions) {
        super(definition, options)
        this.addData()
    }
    private addData() {
        //do stuff
    }
}  

function _limitedRequest(schema: mg.Schema, options = 200) {
    schema.pre("find", function (next) {
        this.limit(options)
        next()
    })
}

declare module 'mongoose' {
    export class _Schema extends Schema {
        constructor(definition?: SchemaDefinition, options?: SchemaOptions)
        private addData(): void
    }
    export function _limitedRequest(schema: Schema, options?: number): void
}
```

Now anywhere in my app i can do:

**otherFile.ts**

```
import * as mg from 'mongoose'
//doesnt work
var test1= new mg._Schema({})
//works
var test2= new mg.Schema({})
```

So VSCode suggests me my class, and IntellIsense works. But it seems there is no implementation of the class.
Webpack doesn´t throw any errors when compiling my code to `bundle.js` but when i try to run my bundle.js with `node bundle.js` it says: *TypeError: mg._Schema is not a constructor*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 2 things:

1. Extend the type definition of `mongoose` with a *declaration file*.
2. Add functionality so the module matches its new definition.

**`mongoose.d.ts`**

Create a declaration file (`*.d.ts`) and include it in your project.

```
import * as mg from 'mongoose';

declare module 'mongoose' {
  export class _Schema extends mg.Schema {
    constructor(definition?: mg.SchemaDefinition, options?: mg.SchemaOptions);
  }

  export function _limitedRequest(schema: mg.Schema, options: number): void;
}
```

**`mongoose-instance.ts`**

Add the functionality you just declared.

```
import mg from 'mongoose';

mg._Schema = class extends mg.Schema {
    constructor(definition?: mg.SchemaDefinition, options?: mg.SchemaOptions) {
        super(definition, options)
        this.addData()
    }
    private addData() {
        //do stuff
    }
}

mg._limitedRequest = function _limitedRequest(schema: mg.Schema, options = 200) {
  schema.pre("find", function (next) {
      this.limit(options)
      next()
  })
}

export default mg;
```

**`consumer.ts`**

From now on, use your local version of `mongoose`.

```
import mongoose from '../path/to/mongoose-instance';

console.log(mongoose._Schema);
```

If you encounter any problems related to default imports, make sure to enable these two flags in your `tsconfig.json`: `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop`.

Comment: Yes this code works. Problem is that `mg._Schema= class extends Schema` gives me warnings, because `_Schema` is not a property of mongoose

Comment: It means the first part of my answer was not correctly implemented — its role is to tell TypeScript about _Schema_ being a property of mongoose. Are you sure `mongoose.d.ts` is included in your project? Please have a look at `files`/`include`/`exclude` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: now i did the `declare module "mongoose"` in mongoInstance.ts. So it works. But it still gives an error when I try to assign `mg._Schema=class extends Schema` it says i can´t assign it, because it is a read only value.

Comment: Do you import it as `import mg from 'mongoose'` or `import * as mg from 'mongoose';`? It can only work with the first approach.

Comment: i modified the code to work without default import/export. so in mongoInstance.ts i do `export {mg}`

Answer (score 0):

Import it like this in mongoInstance.ts:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
```

Export class in mongoInstance.ts

```
export class _Schema extends mg.Schema { ...
```

And in your otherFile.ts

```
import { _Schema} from "./otherFile";
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your awnser. But this doesn´t work. I can´t just import mongoose, because mongoose has no default export. And if i add the import statment to otherFile.ts also doesn´t changes the error message. (And i dont´t want to explicit import my _Schema, i thought this works with the Mongoose module augmentation

Comment: Importing mongoose like that should work. If you want to import it in otherFile.ts make sure to export the class in mongoInstance.ts. I advise against patching an existing module as it would be hard for other developers to understand what you're doing.

Comment: ok i unterstand that. But when i just export my function and _Schema class, then I often find myself importing mongoose and the schema, which means many import statements when complexity grows. Is there a way to do it without explicit importing of _Schema?