# module augmentation on node module that exports class: how to add instance property?

Tags: node.js, typescript

**Update**: *I found exactly the same question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/6xda8q/how_to_augment_an_external_export/). Still looking for an answer though, since on Reddit, only a hack in `node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts` is proposed, which I rather not touch for obvious reasons.*

I'm using the [`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws) node module to create a socket server. Its [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ws/index.d.ts) are of the following structure:

```js
declare class WebSocket extends events.EventEmitter {
    // ...
}

declare namespace WebSocket {
    // ...
}

export = WebSocket;
```

What is the correct way of extending the typings so that I can add an instance property `id` to a `WebSocket` class? I tried the following in a regular typescript(`.ts`) file:

```
class WebSocketServerWithId extends WebSocket {
    id: number;
}
```

Which returns `[ts] Type 'typeof WebSocket' is not a constructor function type. [2507]`. I've also tried to use the approach in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389424/typescript-extend-module-augmentation) with the same error as a result. I've read the documentation on [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) but still am confused.

Anyone knows hows to add an instance property to a class defined and exported in an external node module? (written in commonjs, meant to be executed in node alone).